# hexbin centers for non empty hexagons

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on an implementation using Mike Bostock's Hexabin D3 script (https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/hexbin).

My question is as follows: how do I use the `hexabin.centers()` function to return the array only for non-empty hexagons? Right now, using this function retrieves the centres for ALL hexagons, even those that do not have any data and that are not rendered / shaded etc.

Please let me know your thoughts -and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right -so to return the centers of those hexagons that are not empty, you must loop through the array created when you pass your dataset through the hexbin function, i.e. `var array = hexbin(data);`

When you are looping you can just pull out the x and y values for each object:

```
array[i].x
array[i].y
```

Am not sure what the point of the hexbin.centers() function is, given most users will be more interested in getting the array of bins that are actually non-empty.